# Failed to find '@attr/colorShadowDark' in current theme

Tags: android, kotlin, themes

I faced some problem when running my app in android studio kotlin

> Failed to find '@attr/colorShadowDark' in current theme.

I didn't use this kind of color code in my layout xml, or it is because of my theme.xml?

this is my theme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Login_NoSQL" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="CustomShapeAppearance">
    <item name="neumorph_cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="neumorph_cornerSize">5dp</item>
</style>
```

theme.xml (night)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Login_NoSQL" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Can someone help me fix this error?

**Update**

I finally found where this error comes from, it was come from this neumorphism code

```
<soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
        style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:neumorph_backgroundColor="@color/teal_200"
        app:neumorph_shapeType="flat"
        app:neumorph_shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance"
        app:neumorph_inset="5dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

But I haven't find any solution to fix this.

is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

try change your theme in style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></style>
```

in manifest：

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App"
    ...
    >
    
</application>
```